# Are there any libraries to provide diagnostics on TPL dataflow blocks?

Tags: task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, diagnostics

We're using TPL dataflow blocks, and we want to get diagnostic information on things like the amount of messages being queued in each block, what the targets for each block are, and maybe some metrics like messages per second.

The diagnostics seem fairly straight-forward to implement, but I'd be interested to hear if there's anything out there that does something similar.

Comment: [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx)?

Comment: Nothing built-in, and some of the metrics used in debug views are actually hard to get, provided by `internal` classes. There are very few libraries (as in ~5) built on top of DataFlow and almost all are abandoned. `DataFlowEx` has no commits since 2017 and depends on obsolete libraries like `Common.Logging` and `System.Data.SqlClient`. One of the reasons is that .NET Core changed the fundamentals like logging, diagnostics, event sources and counters. And most .NET devs never knew about DataFlow to begin with

Comment: The connectivity and buffering metrics you want require reflection. There was a [Dataflow Visualizer](https://github.com/oshvartz/tpldataflow-debuggervisualizer) project that used to display a graph of the mesh, but wasn't updated to work with VS 2017. You could use parts of it to generate your own graph perhaps. To collect statistics, I used reflection in the past to collect pending items and detects possible stalling, eg if the counts were the same after 3 polls, something was wrong.

Comment: The diagnostic landscape has changed as well. The new [Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity?view=net-5.0), [ActivitySource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activitysource?view=net-5.0) and [ActivityContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activitycontext?view=net-5.0) built for [distributed tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-collection-walkthroughs) can be used to trace Dataflow calls as well

Comment: The [dataflow source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src) itself only raises [a few high level ETW events](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/DataflowEtwProvider.cs). DataFlow is built for high throughput and low latency, so publishing lots of metrics is avoided. Dataflow can't take a dependency on `ILogger` either, which leaves tracing, logging and metrics to the developer code.